# How to use Events (GdkEvents) in Glade

Tags: application-development, gtk3, glade

When selecting a widget, in the common tab you can find the events control.

[image: Glade Gdk Events]

What is it for? How to use it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is used to enable and disable x events (they aren't all enabled by default). You can use them by assigning a handler to them in the signals tab under "GtkWidget".